# How to place a character below a function in Latex?

Tags: math, latex

Is it possible to place a character or a formula below an other part of a larger formula in Latex?

```
foo f(x) = ...
 x
```

In case that this example is not clear. I'd like to make one of my custom functions - just defined as `\text{foo}` in a math environment - look like one of the built-in functions like sum, min or max which accept parameters that are placed above or below the function symbol.

Simply using `\text{foo}_x` does not work.

Comment: Check `\underset`. Anyway, this is better asked on http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `\underset` provided by the `amsmath` package. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underset{below}{above}$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: no. Don't do this if your intent is to declare a new operator, like lim, sup or inf. Use @hanoosh's answer instead. Using `\text` won't give the results you want if the surrounding text has a fancy font (like inside a theorem, or on a Beamer slide).

Answer (score 11):

You can declare the foo as a math operator. Then use it in any equation environment. See below

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{foo} %in preamble

\begin{align}
   \foo_x f(x) = ...
\end{align}
```

Comment: Note the star in `\DeclareMathOperator*`. This triggers the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

Following the line of the answer by @hanoosh, if you need you can even do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \foo_{x\atop y} f(x,y)
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Only `\DeclareMathOperator*` is powered by package `amsmath` while, for example,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \sum_{x\atop y} f(x,y)
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

compiles not needing any AMS package.